# STM32 - How to run the USB DFU In application programming, in Linux command line

Tags: stm32

I'm using the [STM32CubeProgrammer](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeprog.html) application in Ubuntu 16.04, running the "STM32_Programmer_CLI" in USB DFU mode, to flash STM32H743 device, with BOOT0 connected to 3V3.
Example for flashing command: `sudo ./STM32_Programmer_CLI -c port=USB1 -w /FilePathHere.hex -v -s`
It works well when the hardware is in bootloader-ready mode, get flashed then it runs the core and open's cdc usb: /dev/ttyACM0.

- The question is how should I flash it while the application is already running. I understand this [feature should ne implemented in the GUI version](https://my.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00403500-stm32cubeprogrammer-software-description-stmicroelectronics.pdf), but it's not mentioned how to use it in linux command line.

Comment: That capability does not exist in the Windows version either, because it is not a capability of the hardware of the chip.  "Note: The STM32 must boot in bootloader mode using boot pins and/or the option bits. Check the  AN2606, available on www.st.com, for more information on the STM32 bootloader." and they show moving a jumper on the boot pin.  There are ways you can write a firmware to enter the bootloader on command, if you firmware is functional enough to receive commands.

Comment: There are several dfu command line tools (dfu-tool, dfu-util, ...) capable of putting your device into DFU mode, provided you have implemented the required DFU interfaces. The USB device library of STMCubeMX should be able to generate the required USB code (see UM1734 document). Does anybody have a description of what needs to be implemented (USB CDC, interfaces, protocols etc.)?

Comment: your software/application needs to provide a usb interface with dfu support and support for programming while the application is running.

Answer (score -2):

Solved by power cycling the device.